# Bug in DatePicker in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, user-interface, swiftui, datepicker, popup

There's a strange behavior with `DatePicker` when its style is set to `.compact`. I think this is a bug from Apple, but not 100% sure. Maybe someone already faced it and has an idea of a solution.

What is happening here is that if I tap on the picker while the `Menu` is open, the picker does not open the popup and then there's no way to make it work, despite the fact that it's selected (see the accent color that changes).

This is the code of a test view I made that shows the issue:

```swift
struct TestView: View {
    
    @State private var date: Date = Date()
    @State private var option: String = "1"
    
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            DatePicker("Date", selection: $date, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
                .datePickerStyle(.compact)
            
            Menu {
                ForEach(1..<4) { index in
                    Button("\(index)") {
                        option = "\(index)"
                    }
                }
            } label: {
                Text(option)
                /// This is useful to avoid the change of width of the grey rectangle due to the
                /// different options text (30m is shorter than 2:30h).
                    .frame(width: 45)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                    .padding(.vertical, 8)
                    .background {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                            .fill(Color.gray.opacity(0.15))
                    }
                    .foregroundStyle(UIColor.label.color)
            }
        }
        .labelsHidden()
    }
}


#Preview {
    TestView()
}
```

[image: app_bug2]

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini You're right, I've updated the question :)

Comment: Seems like a nasty bug